# Traversing in a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, traversal

I am trying to traverse from bottom through the white pixels present in the hand. Its tracing only some pixels and then its not working. I am unable to find the reason. The image is given below. Am trying to traverse through the white pixels and am creating an exact copy so that the traversal is assured..

[image]

The code is as follows..

```
I=imread('data\out1.jpg');
img = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
image=zeros(240,120);
for i=1:240
    for j=1:120
        if(img(i,j)==1)
        image(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
imshow(image);
x=240;y=37;count=0;
im=zeros(240,120);
dir=7;

whitecount=nnz(image);

while(count < whitecount)

    if(mod(dir,2)==1)
        dir=dir+6;
        dir=mod(dir,8);
    elseif(mod(dir,2)==0)
        dir=dir+7;
        dir=mod(dir,8);
    end

    for i=1:8
        if(dir==0)
            xx=x;
            yy=y+1;
        elseif(dir==1)
            xx=x-1;
            yy=y+1;
        elseif(dir==2)
            xx=x-1;
            yy=y;
        elseif(dir==3)
            xx=x-1;
            yy=y-1;
        elseif(dir==4)
            xx=x;
            yy=y-1;
        elseif(dir==5)
            xx=x+1;
            yy=y-1;
        elseif(dir==6)
            xx=x+1;
            yy=y;
        elseif(dir==7)
            xx=x+1;
            yy=y+1;
        end

        if(xx < 241 && xx > 0 && yy>0 && yy<241)
            if(image(xx,yy)==1)
                x=xx;
                y=yy;
                im(x,y)=1;
                count=count+1;
            end
        end
        dir=dir+1;

    end
    end
    figure,imshow(im);
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you'd like to achieve, can you be more specific?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the white pixels touching the boundaries of the image could be an issue.

Comment: I want to traverse through the white pixels. But am unable to achieve that.

Comment: I have changed the code... Please check it out and help me..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your algorithm. You are using only a local decision, and at some direction going backwards has a higher priority than going forwards.

Take a look at the A* algorithm, it's suitable for your case.

Comment: Even though it has priority, a checking is carried out to see if it is the previous pixel itself. That does not help??

Comment: and also, there is only single path here.. how does finding the shortest path help?

Comment: The single path is the shortest one. The complexity is `O(pathlength)` if there is only a single path.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has discontinuities, which is why the algorithm fails. When to enlarge the image, the discontinuities are visible. You need to dilate the image [Image Dilation-wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29). You can achieve this in MATLAB with the command:

```
se = strel('square',2);
img = imdilate(img,se);
```

The code shows how to use a structuring element and then dilate the image with the structuring. For your purpose, try to use a small structuring element, which will help you find a path very close to the one seen in the original image.

More information on structuring element [strel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) and dilation [imdilate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) is available here